# Oracle docker-compose

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose

I am writing a docker-compose.yml using oracle image, I did success run the image using default parameters:

- Database: ORCLCDB -> SID
- Username: sys -> sysdba
- Password: Oradoc_db1

*(got that on docker instructions page after proceed to checkout https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition)*

My question is how do I customize these parameters ?

I tried do like I did before with postgre, adding "environment" field on my yml for example:

```
version: '3'

services:
  database-container:
    image: store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
    environment:
      DB_SID: "database_test"
      username: "test"
      password: "admin"
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
    volumes:
      - ./.data/oracle:/opt/oracle/oradata
    networks:
      - compose-network

networks:
  compose-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Surely I typed fields in "environment" wrong, but I didn't found any documentation that explain this info